# how to add virtual host when creating .Net Aspire RabbitMQ Container?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, rabbitmq, dotnet-aspire

How to add virtual host when creating .Net Aspire RabbitMQ Container?

```cs
var RabbitMQ = builder.AddRabbitMQContainer("messagingRabbitMQ");
```

Code I'm using to connect from the client apps.

```cs
var connection = registrationContext.GetRequiredService<IConnection>();

configurator.Host(new Uri($"amqp://{connection.Endpoint.HostName}:{connection.Endpoint.Port}"),
    rabbitMqConfiguration.VirtualHost, host =>
    {
        host.Username(rabbitMqConfiguration.Username);
        host.Password(DefaultSettings.Instance.RabbitMqPassword);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to specify a virtual host for RabbitMQ, you usually include it as part of the connection string when setting up your RabbitMQ client.

Here's an example of how you might configure RabbitMQ in a .NET application with a virtual host:

```cs
services.AddRabbitMQ(options =>
{
    options.HostName = "your-rabbitmq-host";
    options.Port = 5672; // Default RabbitMQ port
    options.VirtualHost = "your-virtual-host";
    options.UserName = "your-username";
    options.Password = "your-password";
});
```

Comment: I have modified my code, if I set the virtual host to say, sample-virtual-host, it will connect automatically to the virtual host?

Comment: Yes, in the provided code snippet, the configurator.Host method is used to configure the connection details, including the RabbitMQ server URI, virtual host, username, and password.

Comment: It will not create vhost. It will just use existing one.